# Encrypt password coming from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

How can I encrypt a password coming from `application.properties`?

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: bob
      password: alice
```

Spring security authentication:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}

//TODO: Not working
//@Bean
// public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   //return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
//}

}
```

I assume `passwordEncoder()` is called and encrypts the password.
(EDIT: If not, how can I access the properties password so I can call the passwordEncoder explicitly?)
But when I try to make a `basic authentication` request using raw password(bob:alice) it doesn't work.

I'm getting `401` and Spring log is `Encoded password does not look like BCrypt`.

How can I encrypt my password and also allow clients to make requests with raw credentials?

Comment: No. But when I add this method raw credentials are not accepted.

Comment: The password from the config is used as-is. In your case plain text. If you want BCrypt you need to put the bcrypt hash in there.

Comment: " when I try to make a basic authentication request using raw password(bob:alice) it doesn't work" sounds like it is working, you just havent added the bcrypt hash

Comment: The config looks like YAML, not properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the PasswordEncoder bean, and put in properties the password encoded by your encoder (not the raw password).

So in your case sth. like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: bob
      password: $2a$10$2T4wM24pGyHuLj12SI/rC.C1gkg4mLGTuzTse3choIVIOtlgsWmPC
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment your password encoder bean. Then temporarily use the password encoder to encode your plaintext password. Log or print the encoded password. Then replace the password in your application properties with the encrypted password. You can encrypt your plaintext password by calling the following method:

```
var encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(rawPassword);
```

Don't forget to remove the code that you used to temporarily log/print your encoded password.